# Is there a way to identify whether a form is submitted in html, WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: html, css, form-submit

I have a form with few fields, validated only in html.
I want to avoid users to click multiple times on the submit button.
Just want to block the button after submitting, so its blocked from second time.
Please let me know if i can achieve this just using HTML and CSS.

Comment: no you can't do that.

Comment: You could hide the button with CSS, but html and CSS are just document languages. They are used to present information not action anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is not possible without JavaScript.

The most minimalist JavaScript scenario I could see to disable the button would be an inline `onclick` attribute on the button.

e.g:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true;" value="Click Me">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

If you want to avoid client-side JS then, with server-side code, you could generate a unique identifier in a hidden input that you can use to check for duplicate submissions on the server.